# Get Distinct Properties Using Linq

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I've a list of object where I've to show distinct properties and the list is given below:

```
public class Questions
{
    public Nullable<int> QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
    public string Options { get; set; }
}

public List<Questions> GetLst()
{
    List<Questions> aLst = new List<Questions>()
    {
        new Questions() { QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "What is the capital of England?", Options = "London" },
        new Questions() { QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "What is the capital of Engand?", Options = "Jakarta" },
        new Questions() { QuestionId = 2, QuestionName = "Who invented computer?", Options = "Thomas Edison" },
        new Questions() { QuestionId = 2, QuestionName = "Who invented computer?", Options = "Charles Babbage" },
    };

    return aLst;
}
```

So it can be seen, in the list there are repeated property values like **QuestionId** and **QuestionName**. So in the front-end, I am using `Razor` to show the list and simply the loop is iterated as the number of given object.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Distinct())          
 {
     <div class="heading">
        <div class="h2Val">
            @item.QuestionId
        </div>
     <div>@item.QuestionName</div>

     @foreach (var item2 in Model.Where(c => c.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
     {
         <div class="heading2">
           <div>
             <input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" value="@item2.Options" />@item2.Options
           </div>
         </div>
     }
     <div>
       <input type="button" class="btn" value="Get Value" />
     </div>
    </div>
 }
```

So my expected output is as follows:

```
1
What's the capital of England?
Option 1: London
Option 2: Jakarta
```

What I am getting now:

```
1
What's the capital of England?
Option 1: London

1
What's the capital of England?
Option 2: Jakarta
```

I tried something like this to distinct the property values as follows but it didn't help at all: (Any better idea to resolve it using `Razor` or `Linq`)

```
aLst = db.Questions.DistinctBy(p => new { p.QuestionId, p.QuestionName, p.Options }).ToList();
```

Comment: In the meantime, if anyone familiar with `jQuery` and have time, please go to this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/vrog5pbn. I didn't post it as separate thread and it seems to be a simple one to be resolved.

Comment: Even under `DistinctBy(p => new { p.QuestionId, p.QuestionName, p.Options })`, the questions are distinct - they have different Options. The actual issue here is that your data structure is inappropriate for the task at hand. It should be `{ QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "What is the capital of England?", Options = new [] {"London", "Jakarta" } }`

Comment: Also, please post your jQuery question separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GroupBy like this:

```
        var questions = Questions.GetLst()
                         .GroupBy(q => new
                         {
                             q.QuestionId,
                             q.QuestionName
                         }, p => p.Options)
                         .Select(
                             grp => new
                             {
                                 Id = grp.Key.QuestionId,
                                 Name = grp.Key.QuestionName,
                                 Options = grp.ToList()
                             }
                         );

        foreach(var question in questions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(question.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(question.Name);

            foreach(string option in question.Options)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(option);
            }
        }
```

I tested this in console and output is:

```
1
What is the capital of England?
London
Jakarta
2
Who invented computer?
Thomas Edison
Charles Babbage
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 @foreach(var item in Model.GroupBy(x=> x.QuestionId))          
 {
     <div class="heading">
        <div class="h2Val">
            @item.Key
        </div>
     <div>@item.FirstOrDefault()?.QuestionName</div>

     @foreach(var item2 in item.Select(x=>x.Options).ToList())
     {
         <div class="heading2">
           <div>
             <input type = "checkbox" class="cbCheck" value="@item2" />@item2
             </div>
         </div>
     }
     <div>
       <input type = "button" class="btn" value="Get Value" />
     </div>
    </div>
 }
```